# Handling events in ES6 Angular controllers

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

I'm experimenting with ES6 classes for my controllers.

Previously if I was listening to a rootScope event with ui-router, I could do something like this:

```
$rootScope.$on('stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) { 
    console.log(toState)
}
```

and toState would easily be accessible.

My ES6 controller currently looks like this:

```js
class NavbarController {
  constructor ($rootScope) {
    this.name = 'navbar'
    this.$rootScope = $rootScope

    this.$rootScope.$on('stateChangeStart', this.activeNav())
  }

  activeNav () {
    console.log('This is called')
    return (event, toState, toParams) => {
      console.log('This is never called')
    }
  }
}

NavbarController.$inject = ['$rootScope']
export default NavbarController
```

From posts I had read I thought I was on the right track however the function I am returning is not called, and I can't figure out how to access the event parameters.

So what is the correct way to handle events in ES6 angular controllers?

Comment: Your code isn't valid JS. Fix all the syntax issues first (too many parentheses, missing arrow, etc. I would also add semi-colons at the end of your statements.

Comment: Apologies for the syntax errors, I rushed the snippet. They are correct now. I follow standardjs hence the no semicolons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
activeNav () {
  console.log('This is called')
  return (event, toState, toParams) => {
    console.log('This is never called')
  }
}
```

You were using incorrect syntax here. Arrow functions need to have "=>" arrow hence their name. You have some more syntax errors in your code. Consider using some IDE or other way of automated syntax checking.

Also name of event is $stateChangeStart not stateChangeStart.

Comment: Apologies for the syntax errors, as mentioned above I rushed the snippet and it did not reflect the code. So with the correct syntax the controller still fails to run any of the returned code from the anonymous function declared with the fat arrow

Comment: I noticed that you are also using wrong event name. It is $stateChangeStart not stateChangeStart.

Comment: Of course... That solved it. I was thrown because stateChangeStart was registering on each state change, without calling the returned function.

Answer (score 1):

Sielakos pointed me to my problem, foolishly using the wrong event. The working snippet is below in case it helps others.

```js
class NavbarController {
  constructor ($rootScope) {
    this.$rootScope = $rootScope
    this.$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', this.activeNav())
  }

  activeNav () {
    return (event, toState, toParams) => {
      console.log(toState.name, toParams)
    }
  }
}

NavbarController.$inject = ['$rootScope']
export default NavbarController
```